# how to display window on turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm a newbie on python. I've just started a free course on Udacity and I don't understand one thing...please I need your support.. I have a Mac with python IDLE. 
I wrote this code:

```
import turtle

def geometrics ():

    window = turtle.Screen() 
    window.bgcolor("green")

    brad = turtle.Turtle()


    i = 1
    while i<4:
        brad.forward(100) 
        brad.right(90) 
        i += 1

    angie = turtle.Turtle()
    angie.shape("arrow")
    angie.color("blue")
    angie.circle(100)

    angie = turtle.Turtle()
    angie.shape("arrow")
    angie.color("blue")
    angie.triangle(100)


    window.exitonclick()


geometrics()
```

when I run it on IDLE nothing appears..on Python shell only messagge like "Restart ....-my path-...."
I try also with sublime but nothing happens..no window open...Where am I in wrong?

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/HighlevelThirstySubversion Works here with proper formatting. Maybe that's it?

Comment: @L_Church, did you look in the repl.it console -- there's an error message and the code doesn't complete.  I.e. doesn't really work.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this, I get:

```
AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'triangle'
```

There is no `triangle()` method in Python turtle -- did you write one but not include it here?  Are you using the standard turtle module that comes with Python or possibly some variant provided by Udacity?

Comment: Thanks for your answer...solved!! there was a stupid typing mistake!!!  LOL